# How to enable OpenXR backend for Oculus Plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, openxr

I have built a VR project for the Oculus Rift S device with hand controllers in Unity 2020.3.43f, and now I am trying to build it.

I get the following error:

`BuildFailedException: OpenXR backend for Oculus Plugin is disabled, which is required to support Unity OpenXR Plugin. Please enable OpenXR backend for Oculus Plugin through the 'Oculus -> Tools -> OpenXR' menu.`

This menu item doesn't exists, this is the closest thing I could find is this:

[image: Option]

Selecting `Set OVRPlugin to OpenXR` allows me to build the project, but the index finger no longer folds when pressing the index triggers for some reason.

I am using the built-in hand controllers prefabs that were imported with the Oculus unitypackage, and haven't changed anything.

Another thing I tried was to select the OpenXR in the Plug-in provider under the XR Plug-in management in the project settings.

[image: Project settings1]

But it disables the Oculus:

[image: Project settings2]

So, how do I enable that OpenXR backend?

P.S., I am using OVRPlugin version 1.78.0

P.S.2, when I debugged the code I noticed that it checks for Android platform support for some reason. Which I don't have nor need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple and weird, I just had to comment/delete the line the throws the error in `OVRGradleGeneration.cs`

```
if (!useOpenXR)
{
    // throw new BuildFailedException("OpenXR backend for Oculus Plugin is disabled, which is required to support Unity OpenXR Plugin. Please enable OpenXR backend for Oculus Plugin through the 'Oculus -> Tools -> OpenXR' menu.");
}
```

This solved all the issues.

Comment: for anyone else who sees this, the line that is on 124 it took me a while to find it